# How can i convert a date in php to SQL format ? (and insert it)

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I'm trying to insert a date , lets say `CURDATE()` to an sql `DateTime` field.

My date is in the format of: `28/01/2008`

When I try to insert it to the SQL, I get just zeroes.

So how can I convert it properly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date));
```

### Explanation

1. [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will try to parse a string (`$old_date` in this case) and understand what date it is. It expects to be given a string containing an English date format or English textual datetime description. On success it will return a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (the number of seconds since January 1 1970). Now we have got a point in time out of that string.
2. [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) then will turn this previously obtained point in time to a format, described in the first parameter, in the example above it is the `'Y-m-d'`

   - `Y` — A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
   - `m` — Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
   - `d` — Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
   - `-` — literally the minus symbol

Here's a [full list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters) of characters you can use in the format parameter string

Comment: strtotime() isn't returnning anything.

Comment: Ok, the strtotime just doesn't work on that format... need to change the '/' to '-'

Comment: I think strtotime doesn't understand the french date format..! You can use my code...

Comment: Look at my answer below, it's because strtotime expects US date format when you're using **/** as a separator, replacing it will indeed help. Refer to [PHP Reference : date formats](http://be.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm trying to insert a date , lets say
>   CURDATE() to an sql **DateTime** field.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$mydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using the European date notation (dd/mm/yyyy) the *strtotime* function will return 0 (which in turn will be converted to 1970-01-01 by *date*) if you don't use **-** or **.** as separator.

So if you want to use strtotime, then you will have to change your date strings just a bit :

```
$olddate = '28/01/2008';
$newdate = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $olddate));
```

$newdate should now contain '2008-01-28'...

Answer (score 3):

```
join('-',array_reverse(explode('/',$date)))
```

to get the standard YYYY-MM-DD Mysql date format.

or just use MySQL' [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to insert a date , lets say CURDATE() to an sql DateTime field.

Why don't you use the MySQL function directly?

```
insert tbl (id, other, datecol)
values(NULL, 'abcdef', CURDATE());
```

> My date is in the format of: 28/01/2008

If it is not CURDATE() you want, but is a PHP variable in dd/mm/yyyy format instead, then see this [MySQL man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for how to format the literals.  Safe formats are `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYYMMDD` without time.

```
$date = '28/01/2008';
$query = "insert tbl (id, other, datecol)
          values(NULL, 'abcdef', '" . date('Ymd', strtotime($date)) . "');";
```

<sub>Note: yyyymmdd is also a valid format in SQL Server.</sub>